# How to add/edit properties files in java application after building war package

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm using maven to build a war package for java application.This war includes some of the property files(comes around 10 files per env) but it needs to be updated based on the environment(dev,test,stage,prod) in following folders.

```
/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/
/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/js
/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/classes/templates/
/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/classes/
```

As of now I have a script in each virtual machine to copy those property files to extracted war folders. But it is cumbersome. Hence i need to update those property files during the build process itself.

**Question**: How we can achieve this in maven or jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build for multiple environments you could use the new [`multienv-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin), providing different configurations as part of your project and building for different environments in a single build.

As an example, your project would provide different environments configurations:

```
src
  ├── main 
        ├── environments
             ├── dev-01
             │   └── first.properties
             ├── dev-02
             │   └── first.properties
             ├── test-01
             │   └── first.properties
             ├── test-02
             │   └── first.properties
             └── prod
                 └── first.properties
```

And the plugin would create different artefacts based on the configuration above:

```
- artifactId-version-dev-01.war
- artifactId-version-dev-02.war
- artifactId-version-test-01.war
- artifactId-version-test-02.war
- artifactId-version-prod.war
```

Then you would no need further scripts but rather deploy each artefact to its related target environment.

Comment: @Nanab4u was the answer helpful? you didn't share any feedback on it?

Comment: Yes Indeed.Thanks.